# What does "ne font plus sourire" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I'm reading [« Internet : trois milliards de prolétaires ? »](http://usbek-et-rica.fr/internet-trois-milliards-de-proletaires/) I don't know What does *« ne font plus sourire »* mean here:

> Un peu moins de vingt ans plus tard, ce texte fondateur est plus que jamais d’actualité : le logiciel libre se démocratise, les échanges non commerciaux **ne font plus sourire** et la culture du don devient populaire. Bref, l’utopie Internet semble se réaliser sous nos yeux.

Comment: It means they are no longer mocked of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That idiom means they are now taken seriously.

Comment: Thank you dear jlliagre. Would you please translate « le logiciel libre se démocratise ?» The free software democratize?

Comment: I would translate it as "free and open source software is becoming more and more popular".